# Implementing a login page with Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

Does Flask have any built-in support for user login/logout functionality? I've found [this add-on project](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but it only seems to provide the pieces to build your own login system. It doesn't seem to be a complete system.

I'm new to Flask, and I'm coming from Django where this is all built-in, so I'm finding it a little baffling that this basic functionality is missing.

Using some incomplete examples I've found, I'm trying to implement an index page that redirects to a login page for anonymous users, and after a successful login, redirects page to the index page. This is what I currently have implemented as a "hello world" login/logout example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flask
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user


app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


class User(UserMixin):
    # proxy for a database of users
    user_database = {
        "JohnDoe": ("JohnDoe", "John"),
        "JaneDoe": ("JaneDoe", "Jane"),
    }

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.id = username
        self.password = password

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.id

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, id):
        ret = cls.user_database.get(id)
        if ret is not None:
            return cls(*ret)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user(request):
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if token is None:
        token = request.args.get('token')

    if token is not None:
        username,password = token.split(":") # naive token
        user_entry = User.get(username)
        if (user_entry is not None):
            user = User(user_entry[0],user_entry[1])
            if (user.password == password):
                return user
    return None


@app.route("/",methods=["GET"])
@login_manager.request_loader
def index():
    if load_user(flask.request):
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))
    #return Response(response="Hello World!",status=200)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return '''
               <form action='login' method='POST'>
                <input type='text' name='email' id='email' placeholder='email'></input>
                <input type='password' name='pw' id='pw' placeholder='password'></input>
                <input type='submit' name='submit'></input>
               </form>
               '''

    email = flask.request.form['email']
    user = User.get(email)
    if user and flask.request.form['pw'] == user.password:
        login_user(user)
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

    return 'Bad login'

@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "ITSASECRET"
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

However, it doesn't work, because even though it seems to login successfully, when it redirects to the index page, it can't lookup the user from the session and redirects back to the login page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to read the documentation for flask-login ... your user class is missing several things that are required (eg isAnonomous)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're confused that auth isn't included with Flask. [Its website](http://flask.pocoo.org/) clearly says "Flask is a microframework". It's not meant to have much baked in. See also http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/foreword/#what-does-micro-mean: "Numerous extensions provide database integration, form validation, upload handling, various open authentication technologies, and more."

Answer (score 3):

Flask-Login is a very basic login manager that is built upon with a few other user management frameworks. I have been using [Flask-User](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User) in production for over 1.5 years with about 30K users and have not had any problems with it (which uses flask-login under the hood). The maintainer is active and has responded to my issues in a timely manner.

It handles user login, registration, lost password, and even email confirmations if so desired. It comes with some pre-built forms if you don't want to mess with that but is easily customizable if you do.

Comment: What's the stability of vanilla Flask-Login as compared to Flask-User?

Comment: Flask login is used my multiple frameworks and the stability seems to be on par with flask user in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe when `login_user` gets called the login is not being persisted. I would make sure however you're doing your sessions is actually storing the login.